# Should I Cache XML feed from localhost API (performance)

Tags: php, xml, caching, localhost

As you can read in the title I have question about php and caching an xml feed obtained from a localhost API.

The xml feed is already cached inside of the API, so that the data don't needs to be read every time from the database. (.NET Service) -> there are multiple feeds running on the server.

The XML feed contains job advertisements (Meta data, keywords and also the HTML), the size of the feeds are different between 100kb and 5mb. Also the time periods how often new data is added is pretty different. (This is often daily or in shorter intervall). As mentioned above this is already handled in the holy .NET Service.

Now my actual question is:
Is it useful to cache the data again for a microsite which have the XML feed as a datasource for rendering a job overview.

If i wouldn't cache anything, for every request the data would be read from the API, filtered and rendered in to an html.

Now I'm not sure if an additional cache would enhance the performance. And where should I probably add a cache. (After the XML is sent back from the API, or after the data is deserialized).

My actual question for the above scenario:

- Is it useful to add an additional cache? (performance reasons)
- If yes, is there a simple php solution or a php library to use?

Thanks,
Hans Rudolf

Comment: Those questions are best answered by comparing the metrics of each of them. And a cache should be after the data is deserialized as most likely the XML is only for the transport of the information and not the information itself. You only need to cache the information itself, not the transport data.

Comment: And libraries you can find on pear, packagist and even via google. Which one is best suiting your needs depends on many things and can't be answered as well. Asking for a library even is off-topic on Stackoverflow therefore. Just saying & FYI.